# Using a while loop to echo mysql_fetch_row for more than 1 row?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
while($dustData = mysql_fetch_row($dustLog))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($dustData); $i++)
    {
        $dustRow = ";".$dustData[$i];
        echo $dustRow;
    }
}
```

I'm using this to return each row to `.responseText` in my main file. I'm trying to transfer a table from the database into a `<table>`.

I'm getting this in my javascript console saying

```
["<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000", " color: #fce94f", " font-size: x-large", "'>( ! )</span> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Final\loglog.php on line <i>6</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>673672</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Final\loglog.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\loglog.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0117</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>680760</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_row' target='_new'>mysql_fetch_row</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Final\loglog.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\loglog.php<b>:</b>6</td></tr>
</table></font>
"]
```

I have no idea what that message means. Any ideas?

Comment: This means that your `mysql_query()` returned `false`, so the SQL query failed to execute.

Comment: That's why you'll often find `mysql_query($query) or die()` constructs, specifically to deal with this `false` return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden in that mass of text is the following:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Which means your query failed (returned false). Otherwise, that should work.